# Ubuntu 14.04.5 update issue - Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file

Tags: 14.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS in my laptop. After installing I found my `sources.list` got corrupted.

```
 $ sudo apt-get update

 output:
  .......
  .......
 W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My sources.list file:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20160803)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 

## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
```

Please can anybody tell me how to fix this? I tried deleting sources.list file and generate again but did not work.

Comment: Try removing apt lists: `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*` then `sudo apt update` let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing apt lists:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then:

```
sudo apt update
```

It should do the job.

Comment: it doesn't work simply for  `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` . Any suggestion will be deeply appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

It should work.